# A proxy server that can add javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy

I'm looking for a simple way to add a javascript to html via proxy server.
I actually found exactly what I wanted here:
https://github.com/axiak/filternet
But it just doesn't work. It uses a deprecated part of a library, and I have no idea how to fix it, as I know nothing about node.js

Does anyone know any other solution that can get the same goal?

Thanks
Yair

Answer (score 0):

I've found on my own computer, that charles knows how to do that exact this. It's a great tool, you should use right now!!!

http://www.charlesproxy.com/